# "wrong constant name" Error when using Turnip with Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, spork

My Turnip test is working normally, but does not work when using `spork`.
I debugged with `pry` and I found that a missing `User`(class constant) causes the error.

What should I do to fix?

```
# working (good)
bundle exec rspec spec/acceptance/features/*

# not work (bad)
bundle exec rspec spec/acceptance/features/* --drb
```

Here is the error when I run with the `--drb` option.

```
Failure/Error: Give a user logged in:
NameError:
wrong constant name #<Module:0x007fd40a19c680>
# spec/acceptance/steps/user_steps.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <module:UserSteps>'
# spec/acceptance/steps/user_steps.rb:7:in `each'
```

This is my spec_helper.rb.

```ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/dsl'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/rails'
  require 'turnip'
  require 'turnip/capybara'
  require 'shoulda/matchers/integrations/rspec'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  Dir.glob("spec/**/*steps.rb") { |f| load f, true }

  WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)

  Capybara.run_server = true
  Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost'
  Capybara.server_port = 8000
  Capybara.default_selector = :css
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    config.mock_with :rr
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.order = "random"

    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    config.include Capybara::DSL, turnip: true
    config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.before(:each, js: true) do
      headless = Headless.new
      headless.start
    end
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

This is user_steps.rb.

```ruby
1.  require_relative 'helper_steps'
2. 
3.  module UserSteps
4.    include HelperSteps
5. 
6.    step 'users are registered :' do |table|
7.      table.hashes.each do |row_hash|
8.       create(:user, class_params_by_row_hash(User, row_hash))
9.    end
10.  end
11. end
```

---

rails 3.2.13
rspec-rails 2.11.0
rspec 2.11.0
turnip 1.1.0
spork 1.0.0rc3

Comment: did you solve this issue? i have the same problem

Comment: I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this problem occurs, but you can prevent it from happening. If you're wrapping your steps in modules, you don't need to pass the `true` wrap parameter to `load`. Change:

`Dir.glob("spec/**/*steps.rb") { |f| load f, true }`

to:

`Dir.glob("spec/**/*steps.rb") { |f| load f }`

This prevents this error for me.

Reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load